# Passing an object from Redux from React causes unnecessary renders?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Im debugging a performance issue in my app. My top level component `App` is re-rendering every time the Redux state changes, even if it's props (from Redux) have the same values.

It's passed 2 props from Redux, one is a string and one is an object.

```
export default connect(state => ({
  name: state.name, // This is a string
  address: state.address // This is an object
}))(App);
```

It's `address` (the object) that is causing the issue. Am I right in thinking that this is because Redux's `connect` function does a shallow compare and thinks that `address` has changed as it's a new object, even thought the values havn't changed?

Assuming this is correct, I believe the solution is to either memoize `address` eg using the reselect module, or use `shouldComponentUpdate` (which seems messier to me). Am I correct that these are the 2 normal solutions?

Comment: You should change your reducer so that it doesn't make a new address object if its value doesn't change.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich It is not related with the `reducer`.

Comment: Everything that changes in the state is related to the reducer, that's the only place where state changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with your assessment, `connect` indeed does a shallow comparison, and if the `address` object is new it will re-render.

I would advise against using `shouldComponentUpdate` to solve this as it can easily lead to bugs where your App does not update when needed.

`reselect` is a fine option for the general case, but in your case there can be another option - you could extract from the `address` object the values in `mapStateToProps`:

```
export default connect(state => ({
  name: state.name, // This is a string
  city: state.address.city, // This is a string now
  street: state.address.street, 
  // etc. 
}))(App);
```

If you need all the values you could just spread the `address` object:

```
export default connect(state => ({
  name: state.name, // This is a string
  ...state.address,
}))(App);
```

Answer (score 1):

> use shouldComponentUpdate (which seems messier to me)

Actually, React Redux already does an [internal `shouldComponentUpdate`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#return-values-determine-if-your-component-re-renders) and only does shallow equality check.

So it's worthless duplicating it in your component.

> either memoize address eg using the reselect

This should be your solution as it ensures that `connect` will skip re-rendering if values are the same.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand actually this always returns a new object

```
export default connect(state => ({
 name: state.name, // This is a string
 address: state.address // This is an object
}))(App);
```

Say your redux state is updated some value but not name or address, redux will call all *mapDispatchToProps* in your App and it would return a new object

I would recommend using reselect for this case, it would really help with performance issue.

Hope it helps

Comment: It's fine if `mapState` itself returns a new object.  What matters is if _one of the fields in the return object_ is a new reference.